# Confusing closures and completion handles

Tags: iphone, xcode, swift, closures, completionhandler

Im a new programmer and am very lost.

I am taking this online iOS dev course and I was configuring collection view cell. 
However, closures and completion handles were used and it was never mentioned before.

```
import UIKit

class PersonCell: UICollectionViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var img: UIImageView!

func configureCell(imgUrl: String) {
    if let url = NSURL(string: imgUrl) {
        downloadImg(url)
    }        
}

func downloadImg(url: NSURL) {
    getDataFromURL(url) { (data, response, error) in
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { () -> Void in
            guard let data = data where error == nil else {return}
            self.img.image = UIImage(data: data)
        }
    }
}

func getDataFromURL(url: NSURL, completion: ((data: NSData?, response: NSURLResponse?, error: NSError?) -> Void)) {

    NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url) { (data, response, error) in
        completion(data: data, response: response, error: error)
    } .resume()

}
}
```

Can someone explain to me what the completion handler is doing after the "getDataFromURL" function. Also what are the closures doing? is "(data, response, error)" getting passed around? How does swift know that "data" is suppose to be NSData and etc in the "(data, response, error)"?
What does the closure after the "dataTaskWithURL" do (is it setting up the completion handler"?

Thank you!

Comment: Reading the documentation should help https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are good questions!

A `closure` is simply a collection (aka block) of lines of code that you can treat like a variable and execute like a function. You can refer to a closure with a variable name and you can pass a closure around as a parameter in function calls just like any other variable, eventually executing the code when appropriate. A closure can accept certain parameters to use in its code and it can include a return value.

Example:

This is a closure that accepts two strings as parameters and returns a string.

```
let closure: (String, String) -> String = { (a: String, b: String) -> String in
                                              return a + b
                                          }
```

Thus, the following will print "Hello Jack!":

```
print(closure("Hello ", "Jack!"))
```

A closure also has a variable type (just like `"hello"` is a `String` and `1` is an `Int`). The variable type is based on the parameters that the closure accepts and the value that the closure returns. Thus, since the closure above accepts two strings as parameters and returns a string, its variable type is `(String, String) -> String`. Note: when nothing is returned (i.e. the return type is `Void`), you can omit the return type (so `(Int, String) -> Void` is the same thing as `(Int, String)`).

A `completion handler` is a closure that you can pass to certain functions. When the function completes, it executes the closure (e.g. when a view finished animating onto the screen, when a file finished downloading, etc.).

Example:

"Done!" will be printed when the view controller is finished presenting.

```
let newClosure: () -> Void = { () -> Void in
    print("Done!")
}
let someViewController = UIViewController(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
self.presentViewController(someViewController, animated: true, completion: newClosure)
```

---

Let's focus on the `getDataFromURL` function you wrote first. It takes two parameters: a variable of type `NSData` and a closure of type `(NSData?, NSURLResponse?, NSError?) -> Void`. Thus, the closure (which is named `completion`) takes three parameters of types `NSData?`, `NSURLResponse?`, and `NSError?`, and returns nothing, because this is how you defined the closure in the function declaration.

You then call `getDataFromURL`. If you read the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSession_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSURLSession/dataTaskWithURL:completionHandler:), you'll see that the closure you pass to this function as the second parameter is executed when the load task is complete. The function declaration for `dataTaskWithURL` is what defines the variable types that the closure accepts and returns. Within this closure, you are then calling the closure you passed to the `getDataFromURL` function.

Within this latter closure (the one you define in `downloadImg` when you are calling `getDataFromURL`), you are checking to see if the data that you downloaded is not nil, and if not, you are then setting the data as an image in a `UIImageView`. The `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ...)` call simply ensures that you are setting the new image on the main thread, as per Apple's specifications (you can read more about threads elsewhere).

Answer (score 0):

make an typealias to understand this is easy :

```
typealias Handle = (data: NSData?, response: NSURLResponse?, error: NSError?) -> Void
//the func should be 
func getDataFromURL(url: NSURL, completion: Handle)
//when you call it. it needs an url and an Handle
getDataFromURL(url:NSURL, completion: Handle)
// so we pass the url and handle to it 
getDataFromURL(url) { (data, response, error) in
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { () -> Void in
            guard let data = data where error == nil else {return}
            self.img.image = UIImage(data: data)
        }
    }
//setp into the func 
func getDataFromURL(url: NSURL, completion: Handle){
    // call async net work by pass url
    NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url) { (data, response, error) in
        // now data / response / error  we have and we invoke the handle 
        completion(data: data, response: response, error: error)
        } .resume()

}
hope it be helpful :D
```